# How to add spaces to an array in perl?

Tags: perl, sorting

The program takes any number of command line arguments (greater than 2) and sorts them [a-z] or [z-a].

```
sort.pl apple mike zebra
```

but when I print the array `@ARGV` it comes out as

```
applemikezebra
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
print join (" ", @ARGV );
```

Comment: `print "@ARGV"` seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible ways:

1. You can use `join`.

   ```
   print join ' ', sort @ARGV;
   ```
2. You can use Perl's special variables.

   a. `$,` is inserted between `print`'s parameters (by default, it's empty).

   ```
   {   local $, = ' ';
       print sort @ARGV;
   }
   ```

   b. `$"` separates array members when interpolated in double quotes (space by default).

   ```
   my @sorted = sort @ARGV;
   {   local $" = ' ';
       print "@sorted";
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually, the default value of `$"` is a space, not the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The "Quote and Quote-like Operators" section of the perlop man page (perldoc perlop) states:

> Interpolating an array or slice interpolates the elements in order,
>   separated by the value of $" , so is equivalent to interpolating join
>   $", @array . "Punctuation" arrays such as @* are usually interpolated
>   only if the name is enclosed in braces @{*}, but the arrays @_ , @+ ,
>   and @- are interpolated even without braces.
>
> For double-quoted strings, the quoting from \Q is applied after
>   interpolation and escapes are processed.

So, one way to print the elements of an array separated with spaces would be:

```
$ perl -le 'print "@ARGV"' apple mike zebra
apple mike zebra
```

To illustrate the function of the $" variable:

```
$ perl -le '$" = "|"; print "@ARGV"' apple mike zebra
apple|mike|zebra
```